# java equivalent Iterator.remove in c#

Tags: java, c#

The code has migrated from Java to C #.

**Java code :**

```
for (List<ItemNY> level : highU.getLevels())
{
    Iterator<ItemNY> iterItemset = level.iterator();
    while(iterItemset.hasNext())
    {
        ItemNY c = iterItemset.next();

        // Code... 

        if(c.getU() < min)
            {
            iterItemset.remove();
            highU.decreaseCount();
            }
     }
}
```

**C# code :** (Code written after convert)

```
foreach (List<ItemNY> level in highU.getLevels())
{
    ItemNY c;
    using (IEnumerator<ItemNY> iterItemset = level.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (iterItemset.MoveNext())
        {
            c= iterItemset.Current;
            //CODE

            foreach (TransactionTP transaction in database.getTransactions())
            {
                int transactionUtility = 0;
                int matchesCount = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < transaction.size(); i++)
                {
                    if (c.getItems().Contains(transaction.get(i).item))
                    {
                        transactionUtility += transaction.getItemsUtilities()[i].utility;
                        matchesCount++;
                    }
                }
                if (matchesCount == c.size())
                {
                    c.incrementUtility(transactionUtility);
                }
            }

            //END CODE

            if (c.getU() < min)
            {
                iterItemset.remove();  //ERROR
                highU.decreaseCount();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to remove an item from IEnumerator, how can I do this?

**Note :** The code written in the C # section is more complete, More code is written in the (CODE) to (END CODE) section.

Comment: Use a list and remove the item from it. No need for using the iterator yourself.

Comment: Replace your whole loop body with `foreach (var item in level.Where(lvl => lvl.getU() < min).ToList()) { level.Remove(item); highU.decreaseCount(); }`

Comment: Really, java lets you do that? An iterator iterates over items, it doesn't contain items. So it doesn't really make sense to remove item from an iterator... And you don't really need to call GetEnumerator explicitly, you can iterate over the items with foreach, iterate over a copy of the list so you can remove items from the original list.

Comment: The `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable` interfaces' contracts - and their generic counterparts - explicitly *forbid* modifying the underlying sequence during iteration(although you are able to create your own implementation that allows it), and will throw an exception if the underlying sequence has been modified during the enumeration. As @SelmanGenç wrote, you need to copy the sequence, iterate over the copy and remove things from the original. Alternatively you can first iterate over the original saving the things you want to remove in another structure, then removing those from the original.

Comment: Thanks for all, for complete guidance.

Comment: I added codes to the C # section. How to use the C variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to remove an item from IEnumerator, how can I do this?

Easy: you don't.

I do not know Java, but that idea does not make sense in .NET. As you can read in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Enumerators can be used to read the data in the collection, but they cannot be used to modify the underlying collection.

As it is also mentioned, `foreach` should be used instead of `IEnumerator<T>` directly:

```
foreach (List<ItemNY> level in highU.getLevels())
{
    foreach (var item in level)
    {
        if (item.getU() < min)
        {
            level.Remove(item);  //Error, you are modifying a collection being enumerated
            highU.decreaseCount();
        }
    }
}
```

You would have to put the elements that match the filter in a new collection so you could remove them from `level`.

```
foreach (List<ItemNY> level in highU.getLevels())
{
    var filteredItems = new List<ItemNY>();

    foreach (var c in level)
    {
        foreach (TransactionTP transaction in database.getTransactions())
        {
            int transactionUtility = 0;
            int matchesCount = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < transaction.size(); i++)
            {
                if (c.getItems().Contains(transaction.get(i).item))
                {
                    transactionUtility += transaction.getItemsUtilities()[i].utility;
                    matchesCount++;
                }
            }

            if (matchesCount == c.size())
            {
                c.incrementUtility(transactionUtility);
            }
        }

        if (c.getU() < min)
        {
            filteredItems.Add(c);
            highU.decreaseCount();
        }
    }

    foreach (var item in filteredItems)
    {
        level.Remove(item);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, another problem occurred. In the loop, I had other code that was dependent on that structure. (//Code...) C variable of type ItemNY is defined, And there are codes like that C.method1() , C.method2() , ... . How to use these methods while I do not have a variable of type ItemNY ? Thanks so much

Comment: @Reza If you edit your question and include that, I might be able to help, but with only that comment it's hard

Comment: The problem is not existe c variable

Comment: @Reza Updated, your comment was outside my active hours :)

Comment: I'm really ashamed. I will deliver this project tomorrow (migration from Java to C #). So I was in a hurry in your answer :). I received an error. error is : " There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'count' of 'List<ItemNY>.RemoveRange(int, int)' "

Comment: @Reza That was my bad, got confused with another class. See the update

Comment: @ Camilo Terevinto, I am really grateful. I do not get any error from the compiler. But it does not work. :(

Is it possible for you to check the program code? Please.

I think this is not possible on this site. Is it possible for you? Code volume is not large

Comment: @Reza Can you explain a little more what you mean by does not work? What happens?

Comment: @ Camilo Terevinto, I run the program with a breakpoint. In the final line of the program (class) I will encounter the following error. Although I think I turned it right. (Migration). The error is in one of the classes and error is : System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: 'The given key was not present in the dictionary.' . If you say, I will email you, or whatever you say

Comment: @Reza That exception comes from a Dictionary, and your code doesn't show any Dictionary. If you post a new question with that error and the code around it (you can follow the stack trace for that), I might be able to help you there

Answer (score 0):

If the true goal is to remove items from the list then I would use [List.RemoveAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall?view=netframework-4.8), with conditions defining which to remove.

If you need the extra counter update then you take a size before and after. Though at least in the presented case there is no need for the decreaseCount method, as it appears to track size of the list, so I would drop the method, and rely on the list Count.